# Subset-Sum Problem Variant with Changing Target Sum - NP Complete?

Tags: np-complete, np

Is the Subset-Sum Problem (SSP) with a changing target sum (which is dependent on the chosen subset) also NP-complete? If so, how would I reduce SSP to this or prove that it is NP-complete in another way?

This is the last step on a larger problem I'm working on and greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: How is it dependent? Can you define the problem formally?

Comment: Do you mean you have a set $S$ and a price function $p : 2^S \to \mathbb{Z}$ and you want to find a set $X \subseteq S$ such that $\sum X = p(X)$?  Beware that such a price function might take exponential space (in $S$) to encode, and hence the problem of enumerating all subsets is actually linear in the input size.

Comment: @Juho, apologies! The problem is: Is solving the question, "Does there exist a set Z of n non­-negative integers {z1,...,zn}, where z is either 0 or 1, such that ∑(zixi) = ∑(ziyi) for i = 1 to n?", NP­complete? I believe that zi acts essentially as a selector of subsets (1 to select, 0 to not select) so the problem reduces to "Is there a subset in x's  whose sum equals the sum of a subset of y's?" Furthermore, each x & y is linked so selecting a subset of x's automatically selects the y's. So this reduces to SSP with set {x1..xn} & a changing target sum (dependent on sum of corresponding y).

Comment: @PålGD, I think what you've proposed - ∑X=p(X) - is essentially what my problem boils down to where the sum of X's equals a function of x. But p(x) in my case is a polynomial so I don't believe this issue you raise exists?

Comment: I'm also trying to solve: Is solving the question "Does there exist a set {z1,...,zn}, where z is any non­-negative integers, such that ∑(zixi) = ∑(ziyi) for i = 1 to n?", NP­complete? Which I'm thinking I can reduce to the Knapsack problem with a changing target limit - zi & xi on the left can be the price & weight respectively and this sets right side to the given limit we're optimizing for. Does that sound right? Perhaps I should start a new question to address this one. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @AmalKahalee Your problem has a trivial solution just taking $z_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden, I'm not trying to find a solution...I'm trying to prove that it's NP-complete. I've already written a verifier for the problem that proves it's NP but now I'm trying to prove it's NP-hard buy reducing it to SSP which is NP-complete (I struggle with reductions). Does that make sense?

Comment: It is not $NP$-complete because the problem has a trivial solution.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying now - "Of course there exists a set Z because you can always just set z to 0." I just re-read the question statement and it's somewhat unclear but it does state that "not all z can be equal to zero" for both the questions I've posed. Many apologies for the confusion and I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @AmalKahalee No, don't start a new question, but please update the question with the proper formal definition.  Also, my worries earlier wasn't that $p(x)$ was superpolynomial, but that the encoding of $p$ itself was.

Comment: In addition to editing the question to clarify the points raised in the comment thread, don't forget to tell us (in the question) what you've tried and where you got stuck.